# Isometry from $\ell^1$ to $\ell^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Is there $f:\ell^1\to \ell^\infty$ so that

- $f$ is surjective
- $\forall x,y\in \ell ^1, \|x-y\|_1=\|f(x)-f(y)\|_\infty$

Comment: Note: When first writing the question, I tagged is "isometry" and apparently, it created a tag with just this question in it. I assume this is not wanted but I apparently can't delete that tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** you can show that $l^1$ is separable, and $l^\infty $ is not.